# Simplify all variable and set them to false in Python

Tags: python, simplify

I'm not a Python master, but can anyone simplify this code because I thought there must be another way of writing this.

```
button1_clicked = False
button2_clicked = False
button3_clicked = False
button4_clicked = False
button5_clicked = False
button6_clicked = False
button7_clicked = False
button8_clicked = False
button9_clicked = False
```

It would be very helpful for anybody to answer me :)
Thank you.

Comment: Keep a list/dict of buttons? it's hard to say without knowing what are you doing.

Comment: `button_clicked = [False]*9` the use e.g. `button_clicked[4]` instead of `button5_clicked` (or use a dict if you absolutely want to 'name` your buttons from 1 rather than 0)

Comment: I think the issue here is the way you're storing your variables...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I only see arguably ugly (self confessed) unpythonic answers I feel compelled to offer another way:

```
button_clicked = {i: False for i in range(1,10)}
```

You can then use e.g. `button_clicked[5]` instead of `button5_clicked`.

The benefit of this is you can now loop over all your buttons easily rather than having to address every single button individually...

Comment: Ok, that's actually helpful as it's the most understandable and simple while also short. I noticed that you had a typo, for example you typed in 2 times which actually should be "False for i in range(1,10)"

Comment: But anyways you solved my problem, congrats, thank you 

Answer (score 2):

a fast and dirty way:

```
[exec(f'buttin{i}_clicked = False') for i in range(1, 9+1)]
[exec(f'buttin{i}_clicked = True') for i in range(1, 9+1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a dictionary like this to store the variables.

```
d = {}
for i in range(1,10):
    d[f'button{i}_clicked'] = False

print(d)
```

```
{'button1_clicked': False, 'button2_clicked': False, 'button3_clicked': False, 'button4_clicked': False, 'button5_clicked': False, 'button6_clicked': False, 'button7_clicked': False, 'button8_clicked': False, 'button9_clicked': False}
```

To access a variable you can do

`d['button2_clicked']` - Gives you `False`.

Comment: what's the point of using a dict if you then need to use `'button2_clicked'` explicitly as key?

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i in range(1,10) :
  vars()['button{}_clicked'.format(i)] = False
```

You can use the `for in range`

Comment: it should be ```False```

Comment: While not technically wrong, this is very unpythonic...

Comment: Can you explain the reason? @Julien

Comment: If this code is inside a module, your answer will have a different effect. better user `vars()[...] = False`.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point. Thank you. I'll fix it. @H.Doebler

Comment: @Julien He did not ask for pythonic or sane or maintainable code, but for 'another way of writing this', so he asked for shorter code having the very same effects. As I assume that the code is indendet to be top-level (not indented), `vars` seems appropriate. If inside a function, @myuan's answer with `exec` currently seems the best way in CPython, since modifying the result of `locals` is implementation defined.

Comment: @H.Doebler if someone asks you how can I better hammer this screw in, your answer should probably not be try this other hammer but try to use a screwdriver instead...

Comment: @Julien Maybe one should, but its definitely funnier to encourage people to mystify their code-bases with `vars` or even better: `exec`. In the end, he now has got a plethora of different ways to chose from.

Answer (score -2):

You can write:

```
button1_clicked = button2_clicked = button3_clicked = button4_clicked = button5_clicked = button6_clicked = button7_clicked = button8_clicked = button9_clicked = False
```

But maybe it is better to keep them on a list or something like that, but it depends on what you want